# Applying same function on multiple pandas dataframe to get dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to apply the same function to multiple pandas dataframe but the resultant is an object while I need dataframe as the result. I also tried using 'broadcast' but that didn't help much

Following is the function which basically assigns a name to the index column:

```
def assign_name(name_df):
  name_df.index.name="Fields"
```

& I am applying it to the uniques & skewness dataframes which basically consists of the number of unique values for each field & skewness:

```
uniques,skewness = (df.apply(assign_name)for df in [uniques,skewness])
```

The data type of uniques & skewness is object:

```
dtype: object
```

Can any one help me out in solving this?

Comment: 1. you do not return anything from your function; 2. you do not assign df to anything (you do not pickle it, you do not insert it into a list, you do not store it in dictionary etc., you do not concat these two dataframes etc.) so last dataframe overwrittes the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pipe` and make sure your function uses `return`:

```
def assign_name(name_df):
    name_df.index.name="Fields"
    return df

uniques, skewness = (df.pipe(assign_name)for df in [uniques,skewness])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def assign_name(x):
  x.index.name="Fields"
  return x

ll = [type(x) for x in [assign_name(df) for df in [df1, df2]]
print(ll)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function remains the same just added a return:
    def assign_name(name_df):
        name_df.index.name="Fields"
        return(name_df)
Storing all the dataframes as list & applying the function on the list:
    list_df = [uniques, skewness,df1_transposed,coltypes]
    list_df = [df.pipe(assign_name) for df in list_df]
Access each data frame as if you are accessing elements of a list:
    list_df[3]